# How to get the discount applied on product using order Id

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have created a coupon code in magento which applies the 5% discount , if subtotal is greater or equal $100.

How can I get the discount amount for a product from using the order Id?

I am able to get the complete discount amount but I want this for individual products.

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app("default");

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('100000009');

 echo $order->getBaseDiscountAmount();
?>
```

[image: Order with coupon]

Coupon code is as following
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('100000009');
$discountAmount = array();
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $discountAmount[$item->getId()] = $item->getBaseDiscountAmount(); //or getDiscountAmount()
}
//do something with the array $discountAmount;
```

Comment: upvoted..The question should be Retrieve discount applied on individual products using order Id....